# Visual Studio Code run external program - configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to run an external program via a Visual Studio Code extension. My scenario is as follows: I am shipping an interpreter that reads the user code and runs it. I want to allow my users to develop using VSCode by providing an extension that would run my interpreter on their code (more advanced features later). The extension should allow adding a configuration to launch.json that runs
[pathToMyInterperter]/[pathToUserProject] and displays the stdout of the interpreter to the output pane.

My extension currently generates the following configuration (which doesn't work)

```
    {
        "name": "Run Project",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "<path to exe>/${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

What properties am I missing and where can I find the documentation for all the available properties?

This is the first time I am using VSCode or developing an extension for it.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) you can find all possible attributes for the `launch.json`.
To start your custom interpreter you set your interpreter to the attribute  `program` (as you already almost did). To tell your custom interpreter which project it should inspect you can pass a list of arguments by specifying the `args` attribute. To use the vscode console or terminal for the output you can set the `console` attribute to `"internalConsole"` or  `"integratedTerminal"`.
Your `launch.json` then should look something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Run Project",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "args" : [
       "${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "program": "<path to exe>",
    "console": "internalConsole"
}
```

If your extension will be a debugger you may want to take a look to [this msdn docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-debuggers).

Comment: I am getting the following error: Cannot launch program 'C:\projects\test\test.exe'; setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help.

Comment: Try to set the `runtimeExecutable` property with your custom path instead of `program`.

Comment: Didn't work. I think it just tells it to use that executable as node.js but then it sends all the node.js command line args to it and crashes.